# Probability - Permutations and Combinations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

So we know the sample space is 12 men, and we know ONLY 2 of them are named Smith. It states disregarding the order of selection, so is it safe to immediately assume "order does not count"? We want to pick 7 men.

So, for a, I wanted to know what exactly "with no restrictions" meant, does that imply we can pick one person, and put them back and pick again? So for a, is it "order does not count, with replacement"?

So then we use the formula $$\binom{n + r - 1}{r} = \binom{12+7-1}{7} = \binom{18}{7}$$

Is this correct? If it isn't, I feel like it's order does not count, without replacement, so it would just be 12 choose 7.

For b), if both Smiths must be included, then how would I go about this? I know both Smiths must be in the event, so there are $\binom{12}{2}$ ways to pick 2 Smiths. This leaves us with 10 people left, and 5 left to pick, so $\binom{10}{5}$. And then we multiply $$\binom{12}{2} * \binom{10}{5}$$ to get our total ways for b.

c) If I could get some hints for c, d, e, and f I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: For $(a)$, I agree it should be $\binom{12}{7}$. For $(b)$, there are $\binom{2}{2} = 1$ ways to choose 2 Smiths, not $\binom{12}{2}$. So the answer for $(b)$ should just be $\binom{10}{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

c) If neither Smith may be included you have only $10$ people left to choose from so the answer is

$${10 \choose 7}$$

d) If just one Smith may be included, you first choose a Smith (there are $2$ ways) and then choose other $6$ people from remaining $10$ (here you may not choose a Smith again) so the answer is

$${2 \choose 1}{10 \choose 6}$$

e) If at least one Smith must be included there will be either $1$ or $2$ Smiths. Now the total number is number of combinations with exactly $1$ Smith + number of combinations with exactly $2$ Smiths.

$${2 \choose 1}{10 \choose 6} + {2 \choose 2}{10 \choose 5}$$

You could also calculate this by calculating the number of ways where no Smiths are included and then subtracting that from number of total combinations

$${12 \choose 7} - {10 \choose 7}$$

f) You can use similar logic to e) here so I am going to leave this as an exercise to you

Comment: Hey, for f) no more than 1 smith may be included, that means we can have either 1 Smith, or no Smith, right? So I think because of this, the following is the answer: $\binom{2}{0} * \binom{10}{7}$ + $\binom{2}{1} * \binom{10}{6}$

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You could also just calculate ${12 \choose 7} - {10 \choose 5}$.

Answer (score 0):

$c$) Hint: If the two Smiths are to be excluded, it is same as choosing $7$ from the $10$ people remaining.

$d$) Hint: First choose which Smith to be included, then choose the other $6$ from the $10$ non-Smith people.

$e$) Hint: look at part $a$) and part $c$), what's the difference?

$f$) Hint: look at part $a$) and part $b$), what's the difference?

Comment: Hey, for f) no more than 1 smith may be included, that means we can have either 1 Smith, or no Smith, right? So I think because of this, the following is the answer: $\binom{2}{0} * \binom{10}{7}$ + $\binom{2}{1} * \binom{10}{6}$